# Google returns http 500 error on redirecting to its OAuth2.0 server

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-apps-marketplace

We're doing OAuth2.0 authentication flow for Webserver app to get the user Id for our marketplace app. As part of the flow, when we redirect to Google's OAuth2.0 server we get a 500 error.

On developer console we see the following -

1. The browser gets redirected to the auth uri. It does a GET of https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth with query string parameters of scope, redirect_uri, response_type (: code), client_id, access_type (: offline). This results into a status response of 200
2. With the above one as referer, it does some more GETs, all of whom returns with status code 200
3. At the end it does a POST of https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/approval with query string parameters of hd, as, pageId (: none), xsrfsign. This returns with status error 500.

We never get a call to our server redirect_uri. The browser shows 500 with a message of "There was an error. Please try again later. That’s all we know."

Any pointer regarding when this can happen will be very helpful.

Note that we have tested a private app earlier, it works correctly, and there the GET call of auth endpoint itself gets a 302 redirect status, which redirects correctly to redirect_uri with code as query parameter. The difference between these two apps are that the one failing has more scopes associated with it.

We have rechecked marketplace sdk configuration and didn't find any particular issue. Also the query parameters in the GET call to the auth endpoint also looks fine.

Comment: Are you using OAuth 2.0 client IDs from Google Developer Console? If you are, you may need to add the ["/oauth2callback"](http://imgur.com/a/48VYK) in your URI origin. That's called the oauth redirect URI.

Comment: Yes, I am using OAuth 2.0 client ID and I have specified authorized redirect URIs as well. I was expecting a callback into this URI once the user clicks on "Allow", but instead the page is showing 500 error.

Comment: I am still facing this issue, any help regarding the same will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Still seems to be an issue 3 years later.

Comment: Had the same issue and changing const google = require('googleapis'); to const { google } = require('googleapis'); did the job :-).